# How to Find a Zombie candidate for Zombie Scanning?

Tags: nmap

I know how to do a zombie scan but my question is how do you find a zombie host?

Comment: Have you done any research on your question? https://gbhackers.com/idle-zombie-scan-nmap/

Answer (score 1):

You can read the documentation of nmap [here](https://nmap.org/book/idlescan.html), who have a section "*Finding a Working Idle Scan Zombie Host*".

It explain that you must find a host with IPID sequences of either ***Incremental*** or ***Broken little-endian incremental***.

You can use a command like `sudo nmap -sA -O -v <IP>` and find which host has a *Incremental* or *Broken little-endian incremental* IPID.